# Oracle Help: count number of rows in one table that fall between two dates in another table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle novice here who is completely stuck. I'm trying to get a count of the number of items that fall between two dates in another table. For example, I have my Staff table that has the people and what time they clocked in.

STAFF

| NAME | CLOCK_IN |
| --- | --- |
| BILLY | 2023-09-26T07:30:35-05:00 |
| DAVE | 2023-09-26T09:45:34-05:00 |
| SARA | 2023-09-27T00:30:07-05:00 |
| HOLLY | 2023-09-27T07:30:14-05:00 |
| DAN | 2023-09-27T10:30:52-05:00 |
| EVA | 2023-09-28T01:15:30-05:00 |

The next table has what the shift is, what time the shift starts, what time the next shift starts, and the work date that it falls on.

SHIFT_CALENDAR

| SHIFT | START_TIME | NEXT_SHIFT_START | WORK_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DAY | 2023-09-26T06:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-26T18:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-26T00:00:00-05:00 |
| NIGHT | 2023-09-26T18:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-27T06:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-26T00:00:00-05:00 |
| DAY | 2023-09-27T06:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-27T18:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-27T00:00:00-05:00 |
| NIGHT | 2023-09-27T18:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-28T06:15:00-05:00 | 2023-09-27T00:00:00-05:00 |

My hopeful result is

| DATE | SHIFT | NO_OF_STAFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-26 | DAY | 2 |
| 2023-09-26 | NIGHT | 1 |
| 2023-09-27 | DAY | 1 |
| 2023-09-27 | NIGHT | 2 |

where it counts Billy and Dave as Day shift on 2023-09-26, Sara as the 1 Night shift on 2023-09-26 even though she clocked in midnight on 2023-09-27, Holly as the 1 on Day shift on 2023-09-27, and Dan and Eva as Night shift on 2023-09-27 even though Eva clocked in at 1:15 am on 2023-09-28.

The data I'm working with is much larger and goes back 3 years, so manually typing in every single date isn't exactly an option, but this gives an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. And I am not allowed to INSERT anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Nothing I have tried has worked so far, but like I said, I'm a complete novice.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery could work for this.  Something like:

```
SELECT to_char(c.DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS ShiftDate,
       c.SHIFT AS ShiftDay,
          (SELECT COUNT(NAME)
           FROM STAFF s
           WHERE s.CLOCK_IN >= c.START_TIME
           AND s.CLOCK_IN <= c.NEXT_SHIFT_START) 
        AS NO_OF_STAFF
FROM SHIFT_CALENDAR c
ORDER BY ShiftDate, ShiftDay
```

You may want to adjust the search times to account for staff arriving early for the shift they're working (does that ever happen? ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer apply` for this:

```
select
   trunc(sc.WORK_DATE,'dd') as "DATE"
  ,sc.SHIFT
  ,v.*
from SHIFT_CALENDAR sc
    outer apply (
        select count(*) as NO_OF_STAFF
               ,listagg(s.name,',') names
        from STAFF s
        where s.CLOCK_IN between sc.START_TIME and sc.NEXT_SHIFT_START
    ) v
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/0sHM9gnK

Full example with test data:

```
with
 STAFF(NAME, CLOCK_IN) as (
    select 'BILLY', to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-26T07:30:35-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'DAVE' , to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-26T09:45:34-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'SARA' , to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T00:30:07-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'HOLLY', to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T07:30:14-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'DAN'  , to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T10:30:52-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'EVA'  , to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-28T01:15:30-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual
)
,SHIFT_CALENDAR(SHIFT, START_TIME, NEXT_SHIFT_START, WORK_DATE) as (
    select 'DAY  ', to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-26T06:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-26T18:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-26T00:00:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'NIGHT', to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-26T18:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T06:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-26T00:00:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'DAY  ', to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T06:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T18:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T00:00:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual union all
    select 'NIGHT', to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T18:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-28T06:15:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'), to_timestamp_tz('2023-09-27T00:00:00-05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') from dual
)
select
   trunc(sc.WORK_DATE,'dd') as "DATE"
  ,sc.SHIFT
  ,v.*
from SHIFT_CALENDAR sc
    outer apply (
        select count(*) as NO_OF_STAFF
               ,listagg(s.name,',') names
        from STAFF s
        where s.CLOCK_IN between sc.START_TIME and sc.NEXT_SHIFT_START
    ) v
```